# Bad practice with the ternary operator

Tags: php, arrays, coding-style, foreach, loops

While writing some PHP, I needed to iterate over a function call that could also return `null`, so I used the following construct:

```
foreach (($object->method() ? : array()) as $thing)
{
    // Insert code here
}
```

My project manager was not fond of this practice and insisted I write something more verbose. I understand his perspective, but if it were up to me, I would leave it as is. What do others think of this practice?

Comment: I think your project manager doesn't know how ternary operator works :) Maybe he insisted because it is "easier" for others to read.

Comment: I think he would be fine with me still using the ternary operator, but he did not want it inside of the foreach initialization.

Comment: `It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious`... I personally don't see any problem with your code, but that's just me. Cheers.

Comment: Does the presented code sample work?? `foreach` requires `as $value`, doesn't it? Not to mention you have one too many opening brackets.

Comment: @Czechnology it does now. I forgot the `as $value` portion.

Comment: @webarto I am not stacking a ternary operator in this case; it's just one.

Comment: @Eric Pruitt, at last I understand the code! :)  Would it be possible for you to modify the method or is it a part of a bigger library? Letting the method return an empty array would be a possible solution (but I don't know your class, maybe you have a good reason to return null).

Comment: @Eric Pruitt, meaning you are not doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have access to modify `method()` ? It seems like the preferred solution would be to make it return an empty array instead of `null`.

**Edit**

If that isn't possible, I think you should do as the project manager suggests or take a decision in the team if this use of ternary operators is ok. I am not a php programmer, and I was a little confused by the semantics of the empty `true` branch.

An alternative to a `is_null()` wrapper around the foreach loop could be a clearly-named wrapper function around `method()` that returns the empty array if `method()` is null.

Comment: That is possible, but I am curious about the practice more than anything, not just this case.

Comment: @Eric The practise of writing readable code? Well, you should follow that practise. Your PM is right. Buy Clean Code by Robert Martin.

Comment: @Gordon But I think it's perfectly readable, and I tend to be picky when it comes to code aesthetics and readability.

Comment: @Eric well, and I think it's not readable :) So does your PM. And what does your team think? See, the thing is, if your PM and your team thinks it's not readable, then it's totally irrelevant what you think about it or if you are picky. There is no I in team. Accept the majority vote. And buy that book ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly cromulent. While this will lead to a PHP 5.3 dependency, it's short and still readable. I guess he took exception to its occurence in foreach, where complex expressions are somewhat uncommon, and hencewhy frowned upon.

Anyway, I sometimes use casting there, which is not more readable, but useful for parameter flexibility (treating a single string as array), not sure if that's really *"better"* in this case:

```
 foreach ( (array)$object->method() as $xy )
 {
```

Obviously, only works if the method returns nothing (NULL). If you can help it, make the method itself return an empty array instead (as good as a boolean false).

Comment: foreach ((array)$object->method() as $thing) dont know why everone loves using so many ( to wrap everthing in.

Comment: Unwarranted concern with operator precedence. But -> does indeed have a higher binding...

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that most likely the manager is against using ternary operators because they can be harder to read. When skimming through the code doing updates, or when code is being reviewed by another programmer, the intent is not usually immediately obvious.

Also, in PHP 6, the ternary operator is being changed from ?: to ??::, which means that if the platform you are programming for will be upgraded to PHP6, this line will need to be recoded.

Comment: Care to support you claims about PHP6 with hard evidence?

Comment: PHP is getting shorthand form for ternary operator `?:` AFAIK, from 5.3 not 6. `Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.`